# How to parse complex data using alamofire object mapper?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I am trying to parse JOSN data using Alamofire object mapper..Done with basic things but stuck with complex things like

1.How can I access values in "settings_data"? (which is best way to access nested object)

2.where can i define .GET, .POST method type and where we should pass parameter ?  like for normal alamofire request we write as

```
  Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
```

is there any good way to achieve the same?

**JOSN Response**

```
{
    "err": 0,
    "result": [{
        "id": 71930,
        "account_id": 40869,
        "status": "enabled",
        "settings_data": {
            "time_format": "12h",
            "timezone": "US/Pacific",
            "fingerprint_versions": {
                "browser.browser-js": 1
            },
            "integrations": {
                "jira": {},
                "datadog": {},
                "bitbucket": {},
                "github": {},
                "trello": {
                    "board_id": "xxx",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "access_token_user_id": 1234,
                    "list_id": "xxxxx"
                },
                "slack": {
                    "channel_id": "xxxx",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "access_token_user_id": "xx"
                },
                "webhook": {},
                "victorops": {},
                "asana": {},
                "pivotal": {},
                "campfire": {},
                "sprintly": {},
                "pagerduty": {},
                "hipchat": {},
                "email": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "flowdock": {}
            }
        },
        "date_created": 1468068105,
        "date_modified": 1493409629,
        "name": "Android_ParentApp"
    }, {
        "id": 71931,
        "account_id": 40869,
        "status": "enabled",
        "settings_data": {
            "time_format": "12h",
            "timezone": "US/Pacific",
            "fingerprint_versions": {
                "browser.browser-js": 1
            },
            "integrations": {
                "jira": {},
                "datadog": {},
                "bitbucket": {},
                "github": {},
                "trello": {
                    "board_id": "xxxx",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "access_token_user_id": 1234,
                    "list_id": "xxxxx"
                },
                "slack": {
                    "channel_id": "xxxxx",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "access_token_user_id": "xxx"
                },
                "webhook": {},
                "victorops": {},
                "asana": {},
                "pivotal": {},
                "campfire": {},
                "sprintly": {},
                "pagerduty": {},
                "hipchat": {},
                "email": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "flowdock": {}
            }
        },
        "date_created": 1468068142,
        "date_modified": 1493409658,
        "name": "Android_TeacherApp"
    }]
}
```

**Model Class - Project.swift**

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Project: NSObject, Mappable {

    var projectId: Int?
    var accountId: Int?
    var dateCreated: Int?
    var dateModified: Int?
    var name: String?
    var status: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience required init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        projectId <- map["id"]
        accountId <- map["account_id"]
        dateCreated <- map["date_created"]
        dateModified <- map["date_modified"]
        name <- map["name"]
        status <- map["status"]
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireObjectMapper

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var projects:[Project] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        fetchData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func fetchData(){
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        let apiUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javalnanda/AlamofireObjectMapperSample/master/AOMsample.json"
        Alamofire.request(apiUrl).validate().responseArray(keyPath: "result") { (response: DataResponse<[Project]>) in
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response.result)
                self.projects = response.result.value ?? []
               // print("sss \(self.projects)")

                for project in self.projects {
                    print(  project.name ?? "")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#easy-mapping-of-nested-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to implement these types of complex json is to split each subcategory to different objects and make them conform to protocol mappable. Then parse the values inside that function. See the example of SettingsModel with time_format and timezone parsed. You can implement the rest of the classes like this

```
    import Foundation
    import ObjectMapper

    class Project: NSObject, Mappable {

        var projectId: Int?
        var accountId: Int?
        var dateCreated: Int?
        var dateModified: Int?
        var name: String?
        var status: String?
        var settings: SettingsModel?
        override init() {
            super.init()
        }

        convenience required init?(map: Map) {
            self.init()
        }

        func mapping(map: Map) {
            projectId <- map["id"]
            accountId <- map["account_id"]
            dateCreated <- map["date_created"]
            dateModified <- map["date_modified"]
            name <- map["name"]
            status <- map["status"]
            settings <- map["settings_data"]
        }
    }


import UIKit
import ObjectMapper

class SettingsModel: NSObject,Mappable {

     var time_format:String?
     var timezone:String?

     override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience required init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
       time_format <- map["time_format"]
       timezone <- map["timezone"]
}
}
```

If you don't wish to create new objects you can parse like

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
                projectId <- map["id"]
                accountId <- map["account_id"]
                dateCreated <- map["date_created"]
                dateModified <- map["date_modified"]
                name <- map["name"]
                status <- map["status"]
                time_format <- map["settings_data.time_format"]
                timezone <- map["settings_data.timezone"]

            }
```

Comment: Thanks for help...i have question do we need to create such multiple classes for each Object..what if we have 50 of such API having each 50 different object like above? is there more good architecture for this scenario?

Comment: If you don't wish to create objects then your response object will become very very large and it will be very difficult to manage.
Separating each entity is a more modular way to implement this.

If you don't wish to create objects you can parse values like
timezone <- map["settings_data.timezone"]

Comment: I have updated the answer with the later approach please check

Comment: Thanks Arvind..Can you please guide on where we should write .GET and .POSt method ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. Could you be more elaborate ?